# Why search input doesn't show typed text?

Tags: html, css

This is the code: http://collabedit.com/a2mjd

I have tried different methods but none of worked to solve the problem. That why the search input doesn't show the text which is typed?

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: create a jsfiddle or something like that

Comment: Your code contains lot of resources (css, js), reduce to the minimal possible code which doesn't work and post it here.

Comment: its actually not my code, its my friend's who needed help but i could figure out the problem by myself

Comment: Here is jsfiddle version, could add it to the question. https://jsfiddle.net/oaupztss/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Impact your `input[type="text"]` with the desired color (which is being overridden by a deeper selector). To avoid using `!important` you could override it impacting a selector such as `.navbar input[type="text"]`.

See snippet:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 32px;
}
body,
td,
th {
  color: #F31215;
  background-color: white;
  color: #94172B;
}
.navbar input[type="text"] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
}
/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

.navbar input[type="text"]:focus {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Motokauppa</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Prätkät <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Husqvarna 701 supermoto</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">KTM Supermoto 450</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ducati Panigale</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Yhteystiedot</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Etsi">
            </button>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- haitarimalli jqueryllä -->
<div id="Accordion1">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- tab queryllä -->

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).</p>
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://images.mcn.bauercdn.com/PageFiles/555744/701sm-1.jpg" alt="701sm-1" class="center-block" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Husqvarna 701 Supermoto </h3>
          <p>9 980€</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/26/27/09/262709f7281b96a074042f7f891e93c4.jpg" alt="KTM450" class="center-block" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>KTM Supermoto 450<br>
        </h3>
          <p>10 390€</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://images.mcn.bauercdn.com/PageFiles/578783/1000x750/1299Anniversario_02.jpg" alt="Ducati-Panigale" class="center-block" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Ducati Panigale</h3>
          <p>30 490€</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.motoshop-vohl.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/IMG_6517.jpg" alt="motokauppa" class="center-block" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Kauppamme</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Motokauppa Pasilassa</h1> 
          <p>Kauppamme on perustettu vuonna 2017. Kaupasta löydät monia eri tunnettuja merkkejä, tutustu valikoimaamme Tuotteet-osiosta.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: the main problem: when typing inside search bar, it doesnt show the text

Comment: When i type something in search bar, it shows up :)

Comment: Works perfectly in chrome but now it does not work in ie. Shows only "etsi" in search bar and not let me type anything?

Comment: No, i mean, when i click the search button, it will not be clicked and doesnt let me write anything inside it, so as well the placeholder wont disappear.

Comment: Try commenting `width: 100%;` on focus like in the snippet above, that might be it since the input grows and could be overlaying the search button.

Comment: Yeah :D IE has always something in the coding. But I checked, so it works perfectly in almost all browser. Afterall the IE is not that much big deal. Once again thank you so much for the help, appreciated :)

Comment: And I use always the newest version of IE